# .Firebase read data in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Hi when I try to get data in document reference it gives me For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method error while using in for loop. I guess it's seems as DocumentSnapshot!.
As I know it should be MutableList<DocumentSnapshot!>. But I am not sure about that.

```
    fun firebase_read() {
    if (mAuth.currentUser != null) {
        val schedule_document = databsae.collection("schedules").document(mAuth.currentUser!!.phoneNumber.toString())
        schedule_document.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            if (document != null) {
                for (i in document) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document` is going to be a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) object.  It's not iterable with a for loop.

If you are trying to iterate the fields inside the document, you can call [document.getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getData()), and iterate the returned Map like you would any other Map in Kotlin.

Comment: How is that performed with firebase with kotlin?